# Flutter Italicize Text in String

Tags: flutter

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to italicize the text, "Connecting", in Flutter?

'String title = 'Connecting';'

I have tried variations on TextStyle but cannot get to work.

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle-class.html

Comment: Thank you @Da2ny, but I could not get the suggestions in that link to work

Comment: 'String title=Text('Connecting', style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),);'

Comment: above does not work

Comment: Just a `Text('Connecting', style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),)`

without assignment works

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is how you can achieve a 'Connecting' String in Flutter.

In Example, there is a Text Widget which is print your String and it takes text style property to give italic font size.

**UPDATE:**
Using RichText Widget

Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TextItalic extends StatefulWidget {
  const TextItalic({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TextItalicState createState() => _TextItalicState();
}

class _TextItalicState extends State<TextItalic> {
  String title = 'Connecting';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RichText(
          text: TextSpan(children: <TextSpan>[
    TextSpan(
        text: "Any Text",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
    TextSpan(
        text: "Connecting",
        style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
    TextSpan(
        text: "any Text",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
         ]), 
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I hope you will get the idea, if this will help you then give the right tick and flag up, Happy Fluttering.

Comment: Thank you Tushar for the detailed reply, but I just need help on styling that one string line, not sure how to implement italic from your example above

Comment: can you provide your code for better understanding?Thank you

Comment: I Update my answer please look at it if it'll help you.